# Functional rules for Spelljammer in D&D 5e

Tags: dnd-5e, spelljammer

Has anyone (official or otherwise) created and published a rule set for the porting  Spelljammer setting into 5e rules set?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Feel free to check out my Spelljammer 5e conversion [here](http://theworstdm.com/spelljammer-5e/).

It's a fairly complete conversion of the original Spelljammer rules for 5e based off of the 2e boxed set. I've been using it to run a campaign for a few years now. Basically I tweaked ship stats, weapon stats and rules for space to be more in line with the 5e rules. I simplified the rules for actual Spelljamming to line up better with the 5e magic rules. I also dumped or hand waved a bunch of rules like since 5e is a less crunchy system than 2e was.

Comment: Website is gone, but you can find it on the wayback machine - https://web.archive.org/web/20180820060641/http://theworstdm.com/spelljammer-5e/

Answer (score 2):

I converted the system and ran about 5 sessions with it. Seemed to work fine. Some things are no longer relevant (for example the Neogi are available officially from WoTC in Volo's, so use those)
[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/koz89dgz1p022wx/Spelljammer%205e%20Conversion.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: your link no longer works. please remove it.